# Python: ImportError: cannot import name DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am compiling this simple code (Using SublimeText 3 and Python 2.7(Already installed on my MAC)):

```
from pandas import DataFrame
data = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [3, 2, 1]}
data_df = DataFrame(data)
```

and I am getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "jj.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas import DataFrame
ImportError: cannot import name DataFrame
```

Note that I installed pandas package using :

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

By the way I looked for similar asked questions and answers, but did not solve my problem.

Comment: Your code works for me without giving any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the python executable running in sublime cannot find the pandas DataFrame module.

You can try running the python file from the command line using

```
python <file name.py>.
```

Alternatively try `pip install pandas`, the sublime python package may not have access to the global python dist-packages

Comment: What do you recommend using instead of sublime ?

Comment: I didn't recommend changing from sublime, just trying a local install of pandas

Comment: It did not work, i will run my code from the terminal

Comment: @ramytanios I'm using PyCharm Community Edition (for free) and I don't face any problem yet, you can check it out!

Comment: @Costis94 Thank you for your help

Comment: @pypypy It is only for once, i dont usually do data manipulation